# How to make hudson aggregate results provided in build artifacts over several builds

Tags: hudson

I have a hudson job that performs a stress test, torturing a virtual machine for several hours with some CPU- and IO-intensive tasks. The build scripts write a few interesting results into several files which are then stored as build artifacts. For example, one result is the time it took to perform certain operations.

I need to monitor the development of these results. For example, I need to know when the time for certain operations suddenly increases. So I need to aggregate these results over several (all?) builds. The ideal scenario would be if I could download the aggregated data from hudson.

I've been thinking about several possibilities to do this, but they all seem quite complicated. That's when I thought someone else might have had that problem already.
Maybe there already are some plugins doing this?

Answer (score 2):

If you can write a script to extract the relevant numbers from the log files, you can use the [Plot Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plot+Plugin) to visualize the data. We use this for simple stuff like tracking the executable size of build artifacts.

The Plot Plugin is more manual than the [Perf Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/PerfPublisher+Plugin) mentioned by @Tao, but it might be easier to integrate depending on how much data murging the Perf Plugin requires.

---

**Update**: Java-style properties files (which are used as input to the Plot Plugin) are just simple name-value pairs in a text file, e.g.:

> YVALUE=1234

Here's a build script that shows a (very stupid) example:

```
echo YVALUE=$RANDOM > buildtime.properties
```

This example plots a random number with each build.

Comment: Mhmm. "Data for the plots are pulled from Java properties files..." There's no Java knowledge here, so I have to ask what might be obvious: What are "Java property files"?

Comment: @sbi, I added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have not persoanlly use this plugin yet, but this might fits your need if you can just generate the xml file according to this plugin's format according to its description.

[PerfPublisher Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/PerfPublisher+Plugin)

Comment: I have no idea how to create a certain XML format from data that a batch script simply writes into files.

Comment: @sbi, If you have control of the batch script, you can make it spit out whatever format you want (XML is just text with a bunch of angle brackets). If you don't have control, then `grep` (or `FIND`) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating the results as JUnit results (XML files) so the results can be recorded by Hudson and will be aggregated by Hudson for different builds.

Comment: I have no idea how to create a certain XML format from data that a batch script simply writes into files.